# Unique ID for mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm making a sign in/out program using mysql and visual basic and need a little help. 
I have two tables `event_in` and `event_out` and under each table I have `event_id`, which automatically generates a number(starting from 1) for each row. I was wondering if it's possible to generate the numbers based on the users. 
So let's say User A comes and signin, 1 is generated into the event_id. Then User B comes and signs in. I want 1 generated for him too...so all User A's event_id will be 1,2,3... and each user's event_id for both the in and out table will also be the same.

With this I will be able to subtract each user's timestamp in `event_out` from that of `event_in` to get how long they were in.

I believe that if I don't generate the numbers separately for each user, then let's say User A signs in (1 is generated for `event_id` in the `event_in` table) but does not sign out yet and then User B comes and signs in (he get 2 for the in) but then he signs out before User A does and he gets 1 for the out and user A gets 2 for the out. So now user and with my current query I will not be able to calculate the timestamp.

```
   SQL = "SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name, g.group_name AS Class, " _
       & "DATE_FORMAT(i.timestamp_in,'%b %d %Y - %r') AS TimeIn, DATE_FORMAT           (o.timestamp_out,'%b %d %Y - %r') AS TimeOut " _       
       & "FROM event_in i, event_out o, user u, groups g " _
       & "WHERE(i.user_bannerid = u.user_bannerid) " _    
       & "AND o.user_bannerid = u.user_bannerid " _   
       & "AND i.user_bannerid = o.user_bannerid " _
       & "AND i.event_id = o.event_id " _
       & "AND o.event_id = i.event_id " _
       & "AND i.group_id = o.group_id " _  
       & "AND i.group_id = g.group_id " _
       & "AND o.group_id = g.group_id "
```

If you have any suggetion on how I can make it simple let me know, I just want to be able to calculate how long they were signed in.

Also is there a VB code that would prevent users from signing in, in, in...like if they sign in in they must sign out before they can sign in again.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that kind of a situation, where you need to map user to event?

I would suggest tables for events and users something like this

**tblEvents**:

- tblUsers_UserId INT
- EventId INT

then table for user would be like

**tblUsers**:

- UserId INT PK AI
- UserDesc VARCHAR()

Then you can actually map user to event and assign events for every user.

Comment: where all my computer scientists and geniuses at? anybody wanna help me out? :/